# When training a small self attention model, raise a GPU Out of Memory Error. I don't know why

Tags: python, pytorch, out-of-memory

When I train a small model, whose target is to do self-attention on several inputs, it raises a GPU Out of Memory Error, as follows.

> RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 2.00 MiB (GPU 0; 11.93 GiB total capacity; 11.45 GiB already allocated; 1.06 MiB free; 15.75 MiB cached)

Here is my code:

```
import torch

class SelfAttention():
    ## this same as self attention code in Transformer

def self_attention_model(input):
    self_attention = SelfAttention()
    distance = nn.MSELoss()
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(instances_slf_att.parameters(), lr=0.01, weight_decay=0.00005)
    num_epochs_slf_att = 10
    for epoch in num_epochs_slf_att:
        output = self_attention(input)
        loss = distance_slf_att(output, input)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer_slf_att.step()
    torch.cuda.empty_cache()
    return output

# It is a dictionary containing users and related items. 
# Items are embeddings and the shape is dynamic.
# Different users have different items. The numbers of items of different users are different.
user_items = {} 

user_output = [] # a list to put outputs
for user in users:
    this_user_items = user_items[user] # this_user_items.shape = torch.Size([1,n,100]). Different user has different n. The range of n is (1,10).
    output = self_attention_model(this_user_items) # self attention code is the same as code in Tranformer.
    user_output[user] = output
```

Here are 1450 users. Each time I train this model after user 900 or 700, it raises this GPU Out of Memory Error. I don't know why. For each user, I have empty the cuda cache.

Comment: You are keeping references from tensors on your GPU, try to cast your outputs before appending them to `user_output`

Comment: @ThomasSchillaci Thanks for your comment. You mean, `user_output[user] = output.cpu()`?

Comment: I mean the use of `.cpu().numpy()`

Comment: Thank you very much. The problem has been solved. I use .detach().cpu().numpy()